# Have the IPA characters from Sylfaen ever been released?

Tags: fonts

[Sylfaen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylfaen_%28typeface%29) as originally designed had a full set of [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA) characters, and they appear in [a paper on the designers' website](http://www.tiro.nu/Articles/sylfaen_article.pdf).  But the version that was free with Windows XP — the only one I've actually used — did not include those characters.  Have they ever been released in any form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2004, it hasn't.
In an excerpt taken from [Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/4315), John Hudson (the author of the font) says this:

> [...] the Sylfaen IPA set, [...] has not been released. It
>   was not intended for release, only to show IPA characters in a
>   database, so it is not as polished as it would be if destined for
>   release.

It has been nearly 8 years since that post, but I do doubt that they were ever released if he never had any plans for releasing them.

John Hudson did however redraw Sylfaen under a new name, "[Nyala](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1214)" which does have some IPA Extensions according to Microsoft.

Comment: +1 thanks for the pointer.  Though according to the linotype website, Nyala has exactly one IPA character: the schwa.